# Cant create a database in a specific folder in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am working on a jailbroken device and I am not developing for the app store.
I create a database in my code in the beginning using this code.

```
 if(temporaryvariable == 0 ) {
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:@"/Library/Myapp/Storage"]) {
                NSLog(@"Creating Direcotory Documents");
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:@"/Library/Myapp/Storage" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
            }
            storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Library/Myapp/Storage/my.sqlite" isDirectory:NO];
        } else {
            storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.sqlite"];



        }
```

The code works fine if I change the db path to root/var/mobile/documents. But when I use the path given in the above code the app crashes with the following error.

> Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x334a30
>   {NSUnderlyingException=authorization denied, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=23}
>   ,,, {
>       NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 23;
>       NSUnderlyingException = "authorization denied"; } with store url file://localhost/Library/Myapp/Storage/my.sqlite
>   Abort trap: 6

I even tried changing the permissions of the storage folder but it doesn't work. Help me with this error please
**EDIT:**
This folder is actually the main bundle of my application on the jailbroken iphone.

Comment: I'm guessing that "Storage" is a pseudo-directory of some sort -- not for real files.

Comment: @ Hot Licks what does that mean?

Comment: Storage is a Folder which I am trying to create in the path.The Storage folder would contain the database

Comment: UNIX has several "virtual" directories/files that don't really exist in the file system.

Comment: Storage is a real folder